# Find a row number based on data from a string in another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which has some user details in different columns, in the last column "G" I have a unique ID which is the string 'UID' I'd like to iterate each row until it finds the one with the UID in column G, I then need it to return the row number for that user.

I've cherry picked different bits of different tutorials and answers and have come up with the below. I've tried debugging and it keeps returning 0.0 for the row.

There are users which do not have unique IDs, could that be the issue?

Any ideas?

```
var data = getQueryString("?"+claim_code);
var UID = data.uniqueid;
Logger.log(UID);

// Find out the row from the UID
var column = response.getRange('G:G');
var values = column.getValues();
var row = 0;
while ( values[row][0] == UID ) {
  row++;
Logger.log(row);
}
```

Comment: You need to give more information's : where does the object response come from? How do you run that code?  Where does that code execute in your function?  Why not showing the whole function...? As it is ,there is little chance we can give you appropriate indication...the answer below is correct but there are so many other possibilities that it's more "guessing" than "knowing" :-) I'm afraid .

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks for your help, I'll make sure any future questions are appropriately bolstered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the while only on values and use !=
Because in that way, it will go over your values UNTIL it find the row you are looking at.
Btw, you might want to limit the range to the specific amounts of rows you have. It's will run much faster than the current G:G that cause it to run on all your rows.
Here is the code that will find the value for you:

```
while ( values[row] != UID ) {
  row++;
  Logger.log(row); 
}
```

Comment: Brill, that works.. however it is always one increment out, I'm guessing because the first row is headers, how would I go about adding +1 to the row string?

Comment: You could initialise row = 1 instead of 0 for example and use values[row-1] in the loop-  it comes so because arrays are 0 indexed while rows in spreadsheets count from 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values of the sheet, and then iterate eachrow to find your value:
The example is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LGv_u_z_DuUpW01o8yMpHkceM3N45G3ruqQ8JtHkNEs

```
function find(){
  var idToFind = "A12347";
  var userRow = findID(idToFind);
  Logger.log(userRow);
}

function findID(userID) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  for(var x=1; x<values.length; x++){
    if(userID == values[x][6]){
      return x;
    }
  }
  return 0; // Error, not found userID
}
```

Comment: What is this getSheetValues function? This script does not read the first row in the data range...and the returned value is not the row number... what's the point to post such a code?